# Update datatable with In condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data table. Value of a column needs to populated using constant and value of other column only if the condition is satisfied.

Below would do for SQL Server.

```
UPDATE table SET ColumnA = 'MyValue.' + ID WHERE SOURCE IN ('1', '2')
```

**How do I achieve the same using LINQ in C# ?**

I can do something like this, but that will keep my where clause extending.

```
var results = from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<int>("SOURCE ") == 1 or myRow.Field<int>("SOURCE ") == 2
select myRow;

foreach (DataRow Row in results.Rows)
    Row["ColumnA"] = 'MyValue.' + Row["ID"] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this Linq query to update datatable

```
List<int> lstSrc = new List<int> {1, 2};

table.AsEnumerable().Where(a => lstSrc.Contains(a.Field<int>("SOURCE")))
                    .Select(b => b["ColumnA"] = string.Concat("MyValue.", b["ID"]))
                    .ToList();
```

this will update your datatable column "ColumnA"

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
where new List<int> {1, 2}.Contains(myRow.Field<int>("SOURCE "))
select myRow;
```

Comment: When answering please add some explanation/description, not just code.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually this can be done through a Join in which you ensure that at least one match exists:

```
var query = from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
    join source in sourceFilters
    on myRow.Field<int>("SOURCE") equals source
    into sources
    where sources.Any()
    select myRow;
```

Answer (score -1):

I could do something like this:

```
public class YourObject
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Source {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    List<string> updateIds = new List<string>() {"1", "2"}; 

    List<YourObject> oldList = new List<YourObject>() 
    {
        new YourObject { Id = "1", Source = "test1" },
        new YourObject { Id = "2", Source = "test2" },
        new YourObject { Id = "3", Source = "test3" },
        new YourObject { Id = "4", Source = "test4" }
    };

    List<YourObject> newList = oldList.Where(i => updateIds.Contains(i.Id))
                                      .Select(j => {
                                                      j.Id="'MyValue.'" + j.Id; 
                                                      return j;
                                                   }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Field("ColumnName") technique to update the column name.

```
  dtNewLCM.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("leafClass")=="0")
    .Select(b => b["leafClass"] = "MyValue1.")
    .ToList();
```